# Fee too high because of a bug in Bitkey application for Apple?

Tags: transaction-fees

I am new here, hello, yesterday evening I sold 0,99930000 Bitcoins with my Bitkey app. But I was very suprised when it went wrong, and it was seen as a minersfee which Haobtc mining as intermediar transferred it. Please help me Haobtc would not help me.

Thanks Edwin

The transaction details are here.
(304f8e03294ba3dbf0cb66ca9dc5f0a2ae99fff4f880ef252c08ed8e75f877de   0.99927577 BTC 454,889 2017-02-26 21:51:03
1HXfAYqpNnawryLgdare836GFJS9KMLa3f 0.99930000
1DouiKSPh4jqaK5YKeHmMEuKkGkvERcvjx 0.00002423)

Comment: Bitcoin: Be Your Own Bank ®

Comment: Welcome.  Please keep asking questions.  That is how we build the community here.  Be sure to take the tour to get a point and so you understand how this system works.

Comment: Hi Edwin, It maybe too later to find this post, and I see your transaction history, there is a back  transaction. Maybe you have get back your bitcoin, that good.    Although it has been a long time, and many versions of the app update, I still need your help to understand the issue. The source address balance (unspent output) is 0.9993,  the fixed trx fee should be 0.0001 at that version, I want to know how many amount bitcoin you want to transfer(what your input in the form field)? I will be very grateful for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new and did my fair work of research. However looking at your scenario if the miner doesnt want to return the fee because of your accident its your problem. Generally good miners will return the fee but that isnt always the case, Its a risk of transactions with cryptocurrency. [txid](https://blockchain.info/tx/304f8e03294ba3dbf0cb66ca9dc5f0a2ae99fff4f880ef252c08ed8e75f877de)

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=360099

Comment: Welcome to you, too.  The tour is well worth taking.